# How to show navigation on post_type=attachment on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a stock photo page on WordPress and I want to display certain number of images per page and then show the navigation at the bottom. I can display the images properly without any problem but the navigation won't display at all. Here's what I have in my template page:

```
                    $args = array(
                       'showposts' => 12,
                       'post_type' => 'attachment',
                       'paged'     => $paged
                      );

                      $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                         if ( $attachments ) {
                            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                               echo '<li>';
                               echo '<a class="th" title="';
                               echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
                               echo '" href="';
                               echo apply_filters( 'the_permalink', '?attachment_id='.$attachment->ID );
                               echo '">';
                               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
                               echo '</a>';
                               echo '</li>';
                              }
                         }
                     ?>
                    </ul>

                    <nav>
                        <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
                        <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
                    </nav>
```

Comment: How have you defined `$paged`?

Comment: Hi Anand, 

Actually the $paged is not declared at all. So declaring it actually solves the problem. I knew it was a stupid problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the $paged variable:

```
                    <?php
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array(
                       'posts_per_page' => 24,
                       'post_type' => 'attachment',
                       'paged'     => $paged
                      );

                      $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                         if ( $attachments ) {
                            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                               echo '<li>';
                               echo '<a class="th" title="';
                               echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
                               echo '" href="';
                               echo apply_filters( 'the_permalink', '?attachment_id='.$attachment->ID );
                               echo '">';
                               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
                               echo '</a>';
                               echo '</li>';
                              }
                         }
                     ?>
                    </ul>

                    <nav>
                        <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
                        <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
                    </nav>
```